# Condition variable not playing well with thread::sleep

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

I'm not sure I understand Rust's concurrency support with `Mutex`es and condition variables. In the following code, the `main` thread sets the `poll_thread` to be idle for two seconds, then to "read a register" for 2 seconds, and then return to "idle":

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Condvar};
use std::time;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Command {
    Idle,
    ReadRegister(u32),
}

fn poll_thread(sync_pair: Arc<(Mutex<Command>, Condvar)>) {
    let &(ref mutex, ref cvar) = &*sync_pair;

    loop {
        let mut flag = mutex.lock().unwrap();
        while *flag == Command::Idle {
            flag = cvar.wait(flag).unwrap();
        }

        match *flag {
            Command::Idle => {
                println!("WHAT IMPOSSIBLE!");
                panic!();
            }
            Command::ReadRegister(i) => {
                println!("You want me to read {}?", i);
                thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(450));
                println!("Ok, here it is: {}", 42);
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(Command::Idle), Condvar::new()));
    let pclone = pair.clone();
    let rx_thread = thread::spawn(|| poll_thread(pclone));

    let &(ref mutex, ref cvar) = &*pair;

    for i in 0..10 {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(500));
        if i == 4 {
            println!("Setting ReadRegister");
            let mut flag = mutex.lock().unwrap();
            *flag = Command::ReadRegister(5);
            println!("flag is = {:?}", *flag);
            cvar.notify_one();
        } else if i == 8 {
            println!("Setting Idle");
            let mut flag = mutex.lock().unwrap();
            *flag = Command::Idle;
            println!("flag is = {:?}", *flag);
            cvar.notify_one();
        }
    }
    println!("after notify_one()");

    rx_thread.join();
}
```

This works as expected, but when the line to sleep for 450 milliseconds is uncommented, the code will often remain in the "read" state and not return to waiting on the condition variable `cvar.wait()`. Sometimes it will return to idle after, say, 15 seconds!

I would think that when `poll_thread` reaches the bottom of the `loop`, it would release the lock, allowing `main` to acquire and set `flag = Command::Idle`, and within roughly half a second, `poll_thread` would return to idle, but it appears that isn't happening when `poll_thread` sleeps. Why?

Comment: FYI, `panic!` takes a format string. `println!("WHAT IMPOSSIBLE!"); panic!();` => `panic!("WHAT IMPOSSIBLE!");`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you expect the behavior to be of this code? When I run it with the sleep either commented or uncommented, the program never exits. The only obvious difference is that without the sleep, there are a great many "You want me to read" printed out.

Comment: The expected behavior is that after about 4 seconds (and many prints of "You want me to read?"), the program will print "flag is = Idle" and "after notify_one()"

Comment: Observed behavior: When the sleep(450) is included, the program seems to either never end printing or will take much much longer than 4 seconds to exit. It seems the `poll_thread` is never notified that the `Command` has returned to `Command::Idle`